# Python function syntax seems to be invalid, but runs

Tags: python, syntax, memory-leaks

All, I've run across a weird surprise in python today. The following code works, but seems to violate python's syntax. I don't know why it would work without a pass statement, or some code, but it does.

```
def test():
    '''Sample docstring.'''

for i in range(10):
    test()
    print "testing", i
```

I'd like to determine why this works, and if it leaves any nasty bits in memory while it runs. It may be the cause of a memory issue I've been trying to track down.

Comment: Isn't it pretty simple to add a `pass` under `test()`'s docstring and see if the memory leak goes away?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There must be at least one statement in a block. A lone string literal is considered a valid statement, even if it is being used as the docstring. It should not cause any memory leaks though, since the compiler omits it in the actual code.

Comment: This is a simplified example. The actual code only shows the leak in the "real world" and I as I go through it, I'm knocking out possibles. You've answered my question, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Python's syntax is explained in the language reference. The relevant parts are:

[7.7 Function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

```
...
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
...
```

So, the syntax for a function is all that stuff up to the colon, followed by a `suite`.

[7. Compound statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-suite)

```
...
suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT
...
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
...
```

So a `suite` can be either a `stmt_list` or an indented block containing at least one `statement`... And a `stmt_list` is just a bunch of `simple_stmt` chunks connected by semicolons on one line.

Finally:

[6. Simple statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html)

```
simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
             | assert_stmt
             ...
```

That shows that a `simple_statement` can be any expression, or an `assert` or whatever else was on the list.

You can click the links on those pages to explore further. An `expression_stmt` is just any expression evaluated by itself, like:

```
dir
2
"cat"
int()
```

Which is a perfectly valid python program that will parse and run, even though it does nothing.

A function's docstring is also an expression. It's just a string that happens to be treated specially by the system.

The special treatment isn't part of the syntax, though. It happens in another phase, long after the parser has built its abstract syntax tree.

I would look elsewhere for the memory issue... :)

Comment: +1 for the detail, and the links to a couple dusty corners of the python ref.

Answer (score 0):

The docstring is also a statement. (An expression statement to be exact.)

It gets special treatment from the compiler, but syntactically it's a perfectly valid statement.

Comment: It's not that the docstring is a statement, but rather that the string literal is a statement; it is possible to create a docstring outside of the function by assigning to `.__doc__`, but if there are no statements in it then it will fail to compile.